# Lightinject - Recursive dependency detected

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ioc-container

Anyway around a Recursive dependency detected issue in LightInject.

I have two business services that take each other and therefore I get a Recursive dependency detected error. Anyone come up with a workaround for this? I'm sure in Structure Map is works.

So I've got something like:

```
public class RetailerService : IRetailerService
{
    private readonly IUserService _userService;

    public RetailerService(IUserService userService)
    {
        _userService = userService;
    }
```

and

```
public class UserService : IUserService
{
    private readonly IRetailerService _retailerService;

    public UserService(IRetailerService retailerService)
    {
        _retailerService = retailerService;
    }
```

Each need to make calls to each other. For example, when I load a User I load the retailer which is a call to the retailerservice and when I add a retailer I need to validate the user which is a call to the userService.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This isn't a problem with the IoC framework, you've made an unsolvable problem. First find a way you could logically construct those two objects manually, and then we can see how we would trick the IoC framework into doing that for you. I also question the responsibility here. You might want to separate the two into three, creating one new service which can load user + retailer or retailer + user, without those two knowing about the other.

Comment: There's no way that StructureMap will be able to resolve this for you. You won't be able to get this compiling if you try to contruct the object graph by hand.

Comment: Ok cheers guys, I've re-worked the services and removed the retailservice dependency from the user service.

Answer (score 0):

This is an ugly smell, which should be avoided in the first place. But you could create a workaround using [property injection](https://github.com/seesharper/LightInject/wiki/Getting-started#property-injection).